# align regression equation at correct position in matlab

Tags: matlab

let us suppose we have following code

```
function plot_test(x,y)
x_constucted=[ones(size(x)) x];
b = regress(y,x_constucted);
y_predicted=b(1)+b(2)*x;
scatter(x,y);
hold on
plot(x,y_predicted);
theString = sprintf('y = %.3f*x+%.3f ', b(2), b(1));
text(x(1), y_predicted(1), theString, 'FontSize', 8);

end
```

output of this equation  is the following figure
[image]

my question is : how to align  equation  out of line? for instance  on top left size? thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you correctly, you want to move the printed equation out of the dots. Check out the text() function description. The first two values define the x and y position in your plot for the text. 
x=1;
y=25;
To move it up, use the new variables in text(x,y,...). Hope that helps.

Comment: thanks  for your help my friend, i use ginput command , but can i do it automatically without  visual inspection?+1 for your help

Answer (score 1):

Some time ago I was looking for a solution for the same exact problem. As you may know, the `legend` command allows to specify a `Location` parameter and one of its many options is called `best`, described in the official Matlab documentation ([here](https://mathworks.com/help/stats/regress.html)) as follows:

> Inside axes where least conflict occurs with plot data

My workaround abuses this feature in order to find the best location to place a single text annotation inside the plot. The code below uses a build-in dataset since you didn't specify how your data looks like:

```
load carsmall;

x = [ones(size(Horsepower)) Horsepower];
y = MPG;
b = regress(y,x);

y_hat = b(1) + b(2) .* Horsepower;
scatter(Horsepower,y);
hold on;
plot(Horsepower,y_hat);
text_at_best(sprintf('y = %.3f*x+%.3f ',b(2),b(1)),'FontSize',12);

function h = text_at_best(txt,varargin)
    l = legend(txt,[varargin{:}]);

    t = annotation('textbox',varargin{:});
    t.String = txt;
    t.Position = l.Position;
    t.LineStyle = 'None';

    delete(l);

    if nargout
        h = t;
    end
end
```

Here is the final result:

[image: Result]

I don't know if this can fit your needs... but developing an algorithm for finding a non overlapping part of the plot in which to place a text looked like an overkill to me. Despite the text being quite far from the prediction line, it's still elegant, clear and comprehensible. The same goes with an even quicker workaround which consists in setting the regression equation as the plot title (blink blink).